# HAVING clause with MAX function returns no data although there is data

Tags: mysql, sql

If there are many records for the student, query below works fine but if the student has only one record then query won't return anything unless I remove `HAVING` clause. Any reason why or any solution?

Thanks

**Note:** What I'm trying to do is to return the latest visa and passport details for the given student but the problem is, I cannot use `ORDER BY` because the data in **visa** and **passport** are not ordered. Latest record doesn't mean that it is really the latest!

```
SELECT
    person._______......,
    student._______......,
    passport.passport_expiry_date,
    visa.visa_expiry_date,
FROM person

INNER JOIN student ON student.personid = person.id
LEFT JOIN visa ON visa.personid = person.id
LEFT JOIN passport ON passport.personid = person.id

WHERE
    student.id = '776'

HAVING
    MAX(visa.visa_expiry_date) AND
    MAX(passport.passport_expiry_date)

LIMIT 1
```

Comment: No `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: Can you give an example of how your data looks? I'm not sure that you will always get the correct result if you have multiple rows (of what? student/visa/passwort?)

Comment: There are hundreds of columns but I'm only interested in `_expiry_date` which has data in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

Comment: An example please. There are four tables involved. So give us the details about 4 tables (leave out all columns not interesting). And you have hundreds of columns? Or do you mean rows? Give us an example for a working student and one for a not working student.

Comment: Where is the equal sign in your having clause?  Will that query even run?

Comment: What does the person table do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this part :

```
WHERE
    student.id = '776'

HAVING
    MAX(visa.visa_expiry_date) AND
    MAX(passport.passport_expiry_date)
```

to this :

```
WHERE
    student.id = '776'
    AND visa.visa_expiry_date = (SELECT MAX(visa_expiry_date) from visa WHERE visa.personid = student.personid GROUP BY visa.personid)
    AND passport.passport_expiry_date = SELECT MAX(passport_expiry_date) from passport WHERE passport.personid = student.personid GROUP BY passport.personid)
```